# ReactDOM is not defined by using react/17.0.1/umd/react.development.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am learning React by **React Quickly, Azat Mardan** that uses React [v15.5.4](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/15.5.4). All examples contain two files `react.js` and `react-dom.js`, for example [hello-js-world-jsx](https://github.com/azat-co/react-quickly/tree/master/ch03/hello-js-world-jsx/js). I would like to use the latest React version that is [v17.0.1](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/17.0.1) and this version does not have these files.

1. What files should I use from v17.0.1 to make [hello-js-world-jsx](https://github.com/azat-co/react-quickly/tree/master/ch03/hello-js-world-jsx/js) example working?
2. The second issue is that v17.0.1 does not have [ReactDOM.render](https://github.com/azat-co/react-quickly/blob/master/ch03/hello-js-world-jsx/jsx/script.jsx#L7). I am getting something like

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
```

Please note, I do not want use `npm` modules only whose files.

Thank you for you support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According an official docs:
you need links for development mode:

```
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

For properly props rename 'frameworkName' to lowercase 'frameworkname'

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      'h1',
      this.props,
      'Hello ',
      this.props.frameworkname,
      ' world!!!'
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  React.createElement(HelloWorld, {
    id: 'ember',
    frameworkname: 'Ember.js',
    title: 'A framework for creating ambitious web applications.' }),
  React.createElement(HelloWorld, {
    id: 'backbone',
    frameworkname: 'Backbone.js',
    title: 'Backbone.js gives structure to web applications...' }),
  React.createElement(HelloWorld, {
    id: 'angular',
    frameworkname: 'Angular.js',
    title: 'Superheroic JavaScript MVW Framework' })
), document.getElementById('content'));
```